# Forms - Auto fill making email validation fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, email

In my form, when the user fills out the email portion, if the email has been previously used and auto fill puts in the information the email shows up as invalid.  How can I change the javascript or JQuery so it does not do this?  Any help would be much appreciated!

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[enter link description here][2]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQD04.png
  [2]: http://jsfiddle.net/M6N24/532/

<form class="container" action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
              <label>First Name
                <input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Last Name
                <input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Email
                <span class="error">Please enter a valid email address</span>
                <input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Phone
                <span class="error">Please enter a valid phone number</span>              
                <input id="phone" maxlength="80" name="phone" size="20" type="tel" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>City
                <input id="city" name="city" maxlength="40" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>State/Province
                <input id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label id="co">Company
                <input id="company" name="company" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Comments
                <textarea id="comments" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" onkeyup="test()"></textarea>
                <input id="sub" type="submit" disabled="disabled" />
              </label>

                <div>                
                    <select  hidden="true" id="00N6A000008yXMN" name="00N6A000008yXMN" title="Product Interest">
                    <option value="">--None--</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="Visiant">Visiant</option>
                    <option  value="Tessellate">Tessellate</option>
                </select><br>

                <select  hidden="true" id="lead_source" name="lead_source">
                    <option value="">--None--</option>
                    <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
                <option value="Trade Show">Trade Show</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="Website">Website</option>
                <option value="Direct Marketing">Direct Marketing</option>
                <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select><br>
                </div>
            </form>

body {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lato;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-title {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Lato";
  letter-spacing: 70px;
}

input {
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 48px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

input[type="tel"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 48px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
}

input:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}


input[type="text"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

textarea:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#co {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

label:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

select,
label {
  height: 50px;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 2% 1%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 15px;
}

#sub {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

#sub2 {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}


label {
  position: relative;
}

.fa {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 65%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s, color .5s;
}

[data-valid] .fa {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #00594C;
}

[data-valid="valid"] .fa {
  color: #00594C;
}

[data-valid="error"] .fa {
  color: #AB0000;
}

.error {
  display: none;
  color: #AB0000;
  font-size: .7em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(150%);
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

[data-valid="error"] .error {
  display: block;
}

input#sub2:not([disabled]){
    background-color: #fff;
    color:  #00AB8E;
}

input#sub:not([disabled]){
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #F68D2E;;
}


#thankyou { display:none;}

#thankyou.success { 
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

#tessellate-page input:focus {
    background-color: #fff !important;;
}

#tessellate-page textarea:focus {
    background-color: #fff !important;;
}

#tessellate-page input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#comments_label {
    margin-top: 8px;
}


@media (max-width: 656px) {
  label {
    width: 98%;
    height: 70px;
  }

   .fa {
    transform: translate(-50%, -45%);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 656px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-self: flex-start;
  }

  label {
    margin-bottom: 20px;

  }


}

function phoneNumber(phone)  {  
  var phoneno = /^\d{9}|\d{10}|\d{11}$/;  
  return phoneno.test(phone);
}

$('input[type="tel"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#phone')) {
      if (phoneNumber($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
        console.log("this works")
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      console.log("this works")
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');
    console.log("this works")

  }
});


function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#email')) {
      if (validateEmail($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
        console.log("this works")
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      console.log("this works")
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');
    console.log("this works")

  }
});


test = function() {
  if ($("#first_name").val() && $("#last_name").val() && $("#email").val() && $("#phone").val() && $("#city").val() && $("#state").val() && $("#company").val()) {
    $("#sub").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```

Comment: this: `<form autocomplete='off'>` exists Not sure if chrome supports it yet or no.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking email validation on textbox keyup event, but jquery does not consider autofill as a keyup event. It can not even read the filled value using autofill.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `keyup` event, you can use `focusout` event to solve your issue.

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6N24/533/)

```js
function phoneNumber(phone) {
  var phoneno = /^\d{9}|\d{10}|\d{11}$/;
  return phoneno.test(phone);
}

$('input[type="tel"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#phone')) {
      if (phoneNumber($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
        console.log("this works")
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      console.log("this works")
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');
    console.log("this works")

  }
});


function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

$('input[type="text"]').on('focusout', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#email')) {
      if (validateEmail($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
        console.log("this works")
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      console.log("this works")
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');
    console.log("this works")

  }
});


test = function() {
  if ($("#first_name").val() && $("#last_name").val() && $("#email").val() && $("#phone").val() && $("#city").val() && $("#state").val() && $("#company").val()) {
    $("#sub").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lato;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-title {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Lato";
  letter-spacing: 70px;
}

input {
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 48px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

input[type="tel"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 48px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
}

input:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

textarea:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#co {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

label:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

select,
label {
  height: 50px;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 2% 1%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 15px;
}

#sub {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

#sub2 {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

label {
  position: relative;
}

.fa {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 65%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s, color .5s;
}

[data-valid] .fa {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #00594C;
}

[data-valid="valid"] .fa {
  color: #00594C;
}

[data-valid="error"] .fa {
  color: #AB0000;
}

.error {
  display: none;
  color: #AB0000;
  font-size: .7em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(150%);
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

[data-valid="error"] .error {
  display: block;
}

input#sub2:not([disabled]) {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #00AB8E;
}

input#sub:not([disabled]) {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #F68D2E;
  ;
}

#thankyou {
  display: none;
}

#thankyou.success {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#tessellate-page input:focus {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  ;
}

#tessellate-page textarea:focus {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  ;
}

#tessellate-page input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#comments_label {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

@media (max-width: 656px) {
  label {
    width: 98%;
    height: 70px;
  }
  .fa {
    transform: translate(-50%, -45%);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 656px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-self: flex-start;
  }
  label {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="container" action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
  <label>First Name
                <input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
  <label>Last Name
                <input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
  <label>Email
                <span class="error">Please enter a valid email address</span>
                <input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
  <label>Phone
                <span class="error">Please enter a valid phone number</span>              
                <input id="phone" maxlength="80" name="phone" size="20" type="tel" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
  <label>City
                <input id="city" name="city" maxlength="40" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
  <label>State/Province
                <input id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
  <label id="co">Company
                <input id="company" name="company" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
  <label>Comments
                <textarea id="comments" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" onkeyup="test()"></textarea>
                <input id="sub" type="submit" disabled="disabled" />
              </label>

  <div>
    <select hidden="true" id="00N6A000008yXMN" name="00N6A000008yXMN" title="Product Interest">
                    <option value="">--None--</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="Visiant">Visiant</option>
                    <option  value="Tessellate">Tessellate</option>
                </select><br>

    <select hidden="true" id="lead_source" name="lead_source">
                    <option value="">--None--</option>
                    <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
                <option value="Trade Show">Trade Show</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="Website">Website</option>
                <option value="Direct Marketing">Direct Marketing</option>
                <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select><br>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest disabling auto fill functionality with some tricks if this is bothering you. Handling a browser functionality with DOM is not always a good way.

Chrome is ignoring read-only fields for auto fill. You can load your input fields as read-only and on hover make them editable

```
<input type="email" name="email" readonly>
```